# Browsers specifically for web development

Tags: browsers, firefox

What are some browser "distributions" (a la linux distributions) that are pre-configured for web development?  I'm thinking for example of an OSX app I can download that contains Firefox already configured with the most popular web development FF plugins)

Comment: If you would like a nightly build of the most recent version of Google's Chrome you should download Google Chrome Canary which is a nightly build of the latest features that the Chrome Development Team has put together.

https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, Firefox, Chrome and Safari already has sophisticate development tools with default distribution. Chrome has `Developer Tools` and Javascript console, Safari has a Develop Menu (enable in Preference), and many more in Firefox's `Web Developer`. So plugin such as Web developer become a handy tool from an essential element for web development like the old days. Many other plugins are personal preference and task specific such as automated testing.